# Writing Objects to Files and Read them

Tags: java, android, hashmap, object-storage

I need my app to save the HashMaps when the app close and restore it's information that are stored on the 3 HashMaps and one ArrayList.

If I remove the two lines with the >> my app is working fine but the data is not stored anywhere so you have to register every time.

Although when I add these lines even if you register you are not able to login which is very odd. Another important thing is that no exception is thrown.

A very important thing my HashMap and ArrayList are in separate classes as static field in order to be accessible by all objects and activities

*This method is the main activity from where my app starts.*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    btnLogin=findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    btnRegister=findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    presenter=new LoginPresenter(this,getApplicationContext());
    >>presenter.loadDataToDB();
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            User curUser=presenter.login();
            if(curUser!=null){
                Intent intent=new Intent(Login_activity.this,
                        curUser.getUserType());
                intent.putExtra("User",curUser.getMail());
                startActivity(intent);
                >>presenter.saveDataToDB();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

*The methods from the LoginPresenter Class are the following*

```
public void loadDataToDB(){
    try {
        EventManagersDB.loadAllManagers((HashMap<EventManager, String>)
                readArrayListFromSD(context, EVENTMANAGERDB));
        UsersDB.loadFromFile((HashMap<User, String>)
                readArrayListFromSD(context, USERSDB));
        ParentsDB.loadFromFile((HashMap<Parent, String>)
                readArrayListFromSD(context, PARENTSDB));
        EventsDB.setAllEvents((ArrayList<Event>)
                readArrayListFromSD(context, EVENTSDB));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void saveDataToDB(){
    saveDataToSD(context,EVENTSDB, EventsDB.getAllEvents());
    saveDataToSD(context,USERSDB,UsersDB.getAllUsers());
    saveDataToSD(context,PARENTSDB, ParentsDB.getParents());
    saveDataToSD(context,EVENTMANAGERDB,EventManagersDB.getAllEventManagers());
}
private void saveDataToSD(Context mContext, String filename, Object list){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(filename + ".dat"
                , mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(list);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private Object readArrayListFromSD(Context mContext,String filename){
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = mContext.openFileInput(filename + ".dat");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object obj=  ois.readObject();
        fis.close();
        return obj;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `So I need my app to save when the app close and restore it's informations that are stored on the 3 HashMaps and one ArrayList.`. Well then we wanna know if you succeed in doing so. Why didnt you tell?

Comment: No i haven't that is my goal!

Comment: Then why are you talking about registering instead of not being able to save an arraylist to file and recreating that arraylist from file? Please rewrite your post to reflect the real problem.